# Google Maps v3: Define overlay(s) for use in multiple maps on same page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm creating an instructional document that will require an overlay element (in this example, a red square) to be used on multiple google maps on the same page.

- I am unable to use the setMap() function successfully - it seems to be applied to the last map on the page.
- I haven't been able to loop the contents successfully either (not shown in this code) - my variable naming syntax is most likely wrong

I have many other overlays to use as well, but kept this example code simple for now.

Here is my (non-working) code thus far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>A.S.G.</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() 
{
        var myOptions = 
        {
          zoom: 17,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.5000000,-105.0000000),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };

        var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"),myOptions);
        var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"),myOptions);


        // Set Border Coords
        var BorderCoords = 
        [
            new google.maps.LatLng(38.5013726888,-104.99825068),
            new google.maps.LatLng(38.4986273112,-104.99825068),
            new google.maps.LatLng(38.4986273112,-105.00174932),
            new google.maps.LatLng(38.5013726888,-105.00174932)   
        ];      

        // Define Border
        var Border = new google.maps.Polygon
        ({
            paths: BorderCoords,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });

        Border.setMap(map1);
        Border.setMap(map2);
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map1" style="width:920px;height:400px;"></div>
    <div id="map2" style="width:920px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found this related [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525106/multiple-google-maps-on-one-page-map-api-3)  
-       
I will attempt to create a function outside of initialize() to draw the border - crosses fingers

Answer (score 0):

When you call setMap it replaces the "map" property of the polygon with a new value, and discards the old value. In this case you first set map to be map1, then replace that with map2, so the expected behaviour is that the polygon is only shown on map2.

The following code should do what you require:

```
    // Define Border
    var Border = new google.maps.Polygon
    ({
        paths: BorderCoords,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    var Border2 = new google.maps.Polygon
    ({
        paths: BorderCoords,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    Border.setMap(map1);
    Border2.setMap(map2);
```